# Jekyll - How to split content defined in .md file into separate elements

Tags: jekyll

I've just installed Jekyll and I'm following a few tuts. I get that you define your content in a .md file in the root and that generates your html file based on the layout file you chose but what I don't get is how to split your `{{ content }}` up.

Say for instance I want one piece of content from my .md file in a `<article>` and the other in an `<aside>` How would I go about doing this? Code in question is pasted below. Thanks

**.md file**

```
---
layout: page
title: Page Test
permalink: /page-test/
bodyclass: page-test
---

Article content
* Hey this is my content!

Aside content
* Test links
```

**Layout file**

```
---
layout: default
---
<div class="post">

<header class="post-header">
<h1 class="post-title">{{ page.title }}</h1>
</header>

<article class="post-content">
{{ content }}
</article>

<aside>

</aside>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One more solution:

In frontmatter declare a variable and call it later via Liquid like so:

```
---
layout: page
title: Page Test
aside: "Here you can even use <strong>HTML</strong>. Even <a href='http://jekyllrb.com'>Links</a>. But it looks nasty."
---

Article content
* Hey this is my content!

Aside content
* {{ page.aside }}
```

Comment: This looks like the way to go, your other method works to but this way I can define the custom content for that page in that page. I'm not after a global include so it could get very messy creating a different include for each page. Thanks

Answer (score 8):

You can use [the `post.excerpt` functionality](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/posts/#post-excerpts).

**_config.yml**

```
excerpt_separator: "<!--more-->"
```

**post**

```
---
frontmatter
---
Excerpt text
<!--more-->
Body text
....
```

**layout**

```
---
layout: default
---
<div class="post">

<header class="post-header">
<h1 class="post-title">{{ page.title }}</h1>
</header>

<article class="post-content">
{% assign contentArray = page.content | markdownify | split: site.excerpt_separator %}
{{ contentArray.last }}
</article>

<aside>
{{ contentArray.first }}
</aside>

</div>
```

Comment: Hi mate I tried this but it came back with Liquid Exception: wrong argument type nil (expected Regexp) in _layouts/page.html. Does page.content and page.excerpt need to be defined somewhere before using it?

Comment: Yes when no excerpt is passed `{{ post.content | remove: post.excerpt }}` generates an exception.  
I've changed my code to more adaptable.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Liquid inside of `.md`-posts. And so you can use `includes` in a `.md`-post.

Example:

1. make a new file called `aside.html` inside a folder called `_includes`.
2. Put some content in it.
3. Call the include in your `.md`-post.

Code:

```
---
layout: page
title: Page with aside
---

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.

{% include aside.html %}
```

More about *includes* › http://jekyllrb.com/docs/templates/#includes

Comment: New doc at https://jekyllrb.com/docs/includes/. Also, it looks like you *can* include .md too but it will show the layout, permalink and other variables, so not great. I couldn't find a way to only show the content.